# Is it true for $a,b$ in a Group G, if $(ba)^{-1}(ab)(ba)= (ab)^2$ and $ab^3=b^2a$, then$ a=b=e$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is it true if $(ba)^{-1}(ab)(ba)= (ab)^2$ and $ab^3=b^2a$, then $a=b=e$?

Here $e$ is the identity element. I can't seem to prove or disprove it. (The problem asks if it is true or false)

EDIT: *The lecturer has told us that the above is indeed true!*

Comment: We can take $a=b^{-1}$; then the above statement is satisfied, but as long as you picked $b$ to be not the identity, neither $a$ nor $b$ is the identity.

Comment: and the last statement is also false, the smallest counterexample is in $S_3$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot an important detail: $ab^3=b^2a$ also needs to be satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Neither statements are true. If we pick $a=b^{-1}$, then
$$(bb^{-1})^{-1}(b^{-1}b)(bb^{-1})=e=(b^{-1}b)^2$$
but for every $b\neq e$, $a\neq e$ as well. The bottom statement is not true in general when the group is not abelian: just consider the dihedral group $D_3$.